# How do I stop Time.parse from returning the current date when my string is empty?

Tags: ruby

I have several places where I use `Time.parse(string).strftime("%m%d%Y")` to get the date of different strings.

Occasionally these strings can be empty `''`. When I parse an empty string with `Time.parse` it gives me the current date.

I need a way to stop this from happening and return `''` or nothing.  Is there a solution to my problem?

```
require 'Time'
s = ''
Time.parse(s).strftime("%m%d%Y")
=> "04232013"
```

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just handle it separately.

```
def format_date s
  return if s.empty?
  Time.parse(s).strftime("%m%d%Y")
end
```

Comment: Is `s.empty?` more "Rubyish"?

Comment: It depends on one's taste, I suppose. Use what you like.

Comment: @squiguy yes - it's more idiomatic ruby to use `empty?`

Comment: `return if s.empty?` would satisfy the OP's request and the Rubyistas :) +1 from me.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the recommended way is

```
Time.parse(s).strftime("%m%d%Y") unless s.empty?
```

When the condition is not met, this evaluates to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

```
require "time"
s = '12/12/2013 05:23:11'
p s.empty? ? '' : Time.parse(s).strftime("%m%d%Y") #=> "12122013"
s = ''
p s.empty? ? '' : Time.parse(s).strftime("%m%d%Y") #=> ""
```

Comment: There's no need for the ternary, "nothing" is an acceptable return value according to the question, a conditional would do but +1 for a good answer.

Comment: @iain I answered as OP asked `I need a way to stop this from happening and return '' or nothing.` Thanks for you complement :)

Comment: I know, that's why you got the vote. I'm just a "less is more" type of person (or a pedant!) :D